# Error in Insert query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am trying to insert into sql database however i keep getting an error

[image]

Below is the query mentioned:

```
 str2 = "Insert into [Snaps](Loc_city,Loc_state,Loc_country,Edu_Hist1,Work_Hist1) values (Loc_city= ' " + soap.data[i1].current_location.city.ToString() + "', Loc_state='" + soap.data[i1].current_location.state.ToString() + "', Loc_country='" + soap.data[i1].current_location.country.ToString() + "',Edu_Hist1='" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].name.ToString() + "', Work_Hist1 ='" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].school_type.ToString()+"')";
                     cmd = new SqlCommand(str2,con);
                     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please help

Comment: do you want to update the existing field or insert a new field into table ? your sql is completely wrong.

Comment: i am inserting not updating as you can see

Comment: Brian's answer was what I was saying. You only need 'Loc_city=...' in update statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the 'Loc_city=...' in your values list. It should just be:

```
 str2 = "Insert into [Snaps](Loc_city,Loc_state,Loc_country,Edu_Hist1,Work_Hist1) values ('" + soap.data[i1].current_location.city.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].current_location.state.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].current_location.country.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].name.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].school_type.ToString()+"')";
```

Answer (score 3):

you dont need the `Loc_city=` on the values.
Jus pass the values separated by comas

Answer (score 3):

The VALUES clause should only contain the actual data, the order and columns its inserted in is already specified in the INSERT statement.

EXAMPLE:

INSERT INTO testTable (colA, colB, colC)
VALUES ('VarcharCol',22,'VarcharColC')

Answer (score 2):

Remove the name of the fields when inserting the values : 
From:

```
values (Loc_city= ' " + soap.data[i1].current_location.city.ToString() + "', Loc_state='" + soap.data[i1].current_location.state.ToString() + "', Loc_country='" + soap.data[i1].current_location.country.ToString() + "',Edu_Hist1='" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].name.ToString() + "', Work_Hist1 ='" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].school_type.ToString()+"')";
```

To:

```
values ('" + soap.data[i1].current_location.city.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].current_location.state.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].current_location.country.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].name.ToString() + "', '" + soap.data[i1].education_history[0].school_type.ToString()+"')";
```

Consider using [SqlParameter with your SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) or just a [string.format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) in order to clean up the query.